# Using Nested Graphs in Sparql

Tags: graph, nested, sparql

I've seen some [papers](http://renzoangles.net/gdm/) and some posts in here, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801869/nested-graphs-in-neo4j) one and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28383932/generate-graph-with-sub-graphs-using-sparql) other one. I am wondering if it is possible to nest graphs in SPARQL and link them with edges like they were resource nodes with an URL. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named graphs provide the ability to link to a graph. This is not nest graph s- it's links from one graph to the concept of the other graph.